# How are discrepancies between the hardware level raid of a raid controller and the hardware level raid of a raid enclosure reconciled?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

How are discrepancies between the hardware level raid of a raid controller and the hardware level raid of a raid enclosure reconciled?

For example if my RAID controller supports the following RAID levels:

RAID 0/1/1E/3/5/6 JBOD
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816151033

And my RAID enclosure supports the following RAID levels:

RAID 0, 1, 1E, 5, 6, 10,and 50
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816102113

Would I be able to support RAID level 50 since the controller does not support it?
Also in this example the cache memory for the RAID enclosure is 256MB but it is 2GB for the controller.  Would I be able to support 2GB cache memory if the RAID enclosure does not support it but the controller does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That enclosure contains its own controller, you talk to it over iSCSI rather than adding an extra controller.